# Unique couple of values + Hibernate and bulk insertion

Tags: java, hibernate, object

my object: http://pastebin.com/FWEGwcL0

I need to prevent adding rows with couple (name; surname) that already exist.
I.e.: I can add (John; Brown), (John; White), (Louise; Brown) but I should prevent adding another (John; Brown).

When I save objects I do saving a List.
This means that if I put the key on DB to let the couple (name, surname) unique, I'm afraid that when I save the list of objects, if one fails, all the other values fails too.

How can i prevent this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Exceptions in JPA are non recoverable if you have attached instances.

From the Spec:

> 3.3.2 Transaction Rollback For both transaction-scoped and extended persistence contexts, transaction rollback causes all pre-existing
>   managed instances and removed instances[31] to become detached. The
>   instances’ state will be the state of the instances at the point at
>   which the transaction was rolled back. Transaction rollback typically
>   causes the persistence context to be in an inconsistent state at the
>   point of rollback. In particular, the state of version attributes and
>   generated state (e.g., generated primary keys) may be inconsistent.
>   Instances that were formerly managed by the persistence context
>   (including new instances that were made persistent in that
>   transaction) may therefore not be reusable in the same manner as other
>   detached objects—for example, they may fail when passed to the merge
>   operation.[32]

Which means once you have encountered an exception you cannot use that session for any further database operations.

Which means you will have to create a new session and then start your transaction once again.

Same is true with Hibernate, if you directly use hibernate API to manage your transactions.

> 12.2.3. Exception handling If the Session throws an exception, including any SQLException, immediately rollback the database
>   transaction, call Session.close() and discard the Session instance.
>   Certain methods of Session will not leave the session in a consistent
>   state. No exception thrown by Hibernate can be treated as recoverable.
>   Ensure that the Session will be closed by calling close() in a finally
>   block.

One way of handling this is that you dont use managed instances instead you use detached instances, in that case you will be closing your session or entityManager after every database operation whether successful or not.

In this case once have closed the session, your objects become detached and further Exception won't have any effect on them.

Came across a nice [article](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/blog/davidvc/archive2007/04/jpa_and_rollbac.html)

Comment: What about saveOrUpdate method? Can i let it understand that for couple (name, surname) that exist it should use the update function instead the save one?

Comment: When you call save, it will try to insert, when you call saveOrUpdate it will do the trick for you, in case record is not present it will insert a new record or else it will update the existing record